# Jquery rename content insite a tag and confirm it

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, textarea

The User should be able to change the Name and then confirm the change. I'm not able to archive it with this code as when I click confirm, it returns like before. 
What am I missing?

Any better way to put this together (which I'm sure there's one) ?

Please check the **demo** where you can also see the `changeElementType`function

http://jsfiddle.net/dLk6E/

js:

```
$('.replace').on('click', function () {
    $("h2").changeElementType("textarea");
    $('.replace').hide();
    $('.confirm').show();

    //Confermation of the change
    $('.confirm').bind('click', function () {
        $('.replace').show();
        $('.confirm').hide();
        $("textarea").changeElementType("h2");
    });


    if ($('textarea:visible')) {
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                alert('You pressed enter!');
                $("textarea").changeElementType("h2");
                $('.replace').css('opacity', '1');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: But you are not doing anything with the value entered

Comment: @mitomed yes, noticed that! but not sure how I can get this value

Comment: I think your code is ok, only thing you should do something with the value entered, something like this maybe http://jsfiddle.net/7gXz7/

Comment: @mitomed looks fine!!! do you know how to put a limit or something? however thanks for this

Comment: what limit, maybe edit the question and update with what you actually want to achieve

Comment: @mitomed ok, I can accept it if you put it as an answewr!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58010/discussion-between-user3699998-and-mitomed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is right but you need to use the value you're entering when replacing it. So the confirmation binding would be something like this (fetching it, and then using it to update the textarea before "transforming" it into an h2 tag.

```
$('.confirm').bind('click', function(){
    var valueEntered = $('textarea').val();
    $('.replace').show();
    $('.confirm').hide();
    $("textarea").html(valueEntered).changeElementType("h2");
});
```

You could be using .on for this as well as of jQuery 1.7 is prefered to .bind.

Another thing I would suggest is whenever you struggle with something like this just put in google (or whatever...) exactly what you want, in this case "jquery get value of input" will get asw first result the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

This way you won't forget it ;)

Update: Maybe a small detail but in the binding I use it would be more efficient to just hit $('textarea') once, so it would be something like this. Something that you may keep in mind (not really an issue here), better to store in a variable than hit the DOM several times.

```
$('.confirm').on('click', function(){
    var $textarea = $('textarea');
    $('.replace').show();
    $('.confirm').hide();
    $textarea.html($textarea.val()).changeElementType("h2");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gXz7/2/)

Comment: This is same as my answer :-)

Comment: Actually, I updated your comment accidentally, yeah it's pretry much the same but look at my comment to your answer. Your answer indeed was pretty much the same as my fiddle in the comments but later  so no need to downvote this one :)

Comment: KIds, please stop it! stackoverflow is not a betting Site!

Answer (score 1):

Here are your updated code and working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dLk6E/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
        var attrs = {};

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    }
})(jQuery);



$('.replace').on('click', function (){
    $("h2").changeElementType("textarea");
    $('.replace').hide();

    $('.confirm').show();

    //Confermation of the change
    $('.confirm').on('click', function(){
        $('.replace').show();
        $('.confirm').hide();

        // you are missing this
        $('.replaceble').html($("textarea").val());

        $("textarea").changeElementType("h2");
    });




    if ($('textarea:visible')){
         $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                alert('You pressed enter!');
                $("textarea").changeElementType("h2");
                $('.replace').css('opacity','1');
            }
        });
    }


});
```

**updated**
jsfiddle.net/dLk6E/1

Comment: it is working for me did you checked it on the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dLk6E/

Comment: Doesn't type new text on textare then try to confirm! doesn't work

Comment: You didn't link the correct fiddle @Ramzan Zafar, just the op's one

Comment: @mitomed thanks i was doing it wrong here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dLk6E/1/